# How to find all sprints in current project using VersionOne Rest API?

Tags: rest, versionone

Please share a sample REST API query to get the list of all sprints in a given project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, you need to know the mapping of UI terms to underlying [asset types](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Asset_Type). What you see as a sprint in the UI is known as a `Timebox` and what you see as a project is known as a `Scope`. You would also need to know that `Timebox` does not have a direct relationship to `Scope`. They are many-to-many through the [sprint schedule](https://community.versionone.com/Help-Center/Version101/Current/Sprint-Iteration-Planning/Sprint%2F%2FIteration_Scheduling) known simply as `Schedule` in the API.

You can use the [query.v1 endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1) to POST the following query:

```
from: Timebox
where:
  Schedule.ScheduledScopes.Name: The Desired Project
```

Or, using the [rest-1.v1/Data endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData), you can GET the following query:

```
<Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Data/Timebox?where=Schedule.ScheduledScopes.Name='The Desired Project'
```